# How passing multi dimensional to javascript and store again in multi dimensional?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have variable in php with multi dimensional array :

```
$all = array(2) {
           [0]=> array(2) {
                            [0]=> string(1) "1" 
                            [1]=> string(1) "a" 
                          } 

           [1]=> array(2) {
                            [0]=> string(1) "2" 
                            [1]=> string(1) "b" 
                          } 
         }
```

I try passing to javascript then store again in array for looping again

trying store to new array (multidimensional) in javascript

like this  `window.a = new array (['1','a'],['2','b']);`

```
var all = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($all); ?>');
    window.a = new array();
    for(i=0; i< all.length; i++)
    {
        window.a.push([all[i][0],all[i][1]]);
    }
```

What is the correct way of doing it???

Sorry minim for experience for javascript Thank you.

Comment: there's a built in function that you can use in PHP, its called `json_encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `json_encode` is going to be a string and not an array. Essentially what you're trying to do is assign a string to a variable without quotations and trying to loop through it. `json_encode` doesn't automatically turn the string into an array suitable for javascript.

`var all = <?php echo json_encode($all); ?>;`

should be changed to

`var all = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($all); ?>');`

However, you're likely to have issues if the json encoded data has a single quote in it to break the string. You might want to look into escaping the `$all` variable with `addslashes` or something similar.

This is just a basic answer, there probably is more ideal answers.